# Bounding the integral of a stochastic return process

Tags: convex-analysis, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to evaluate an issue regarding convexity in continuous mathematical finance.  But I am not sure if (1) my general conclusion is right and (2) if so, how to prove it.

Suppose we have a 'return' process that is Brownian.  At any time $t$, its instantaneous value is $r_t$.

If we start with a value of 1.0 and compound continuously, the value after a time $t_f$ has passed is, I think,

$$\int_0^{t_f}e^{r_t}dt  $$

Now, there is a fixed value $\hat r$ such that

$$\int_0^{t_f}e^{\hat r}dt  $$

has the same value - i.e., it is the fixed rate that gives the same result.

Intuitively, it seems like $\hat r<E[r_t]$ due to convexity (as well as extending the discrete time results to continuous time).

Is that right, and how would one most readily start a proof?